# openejb @OneToMany leads to NullPointerException

Tags: java, openejb

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong in my little test case? I use openEjb for unit tests in maven an eclipse using testNG. I got the container running, configured a datasource using hsqld and managed to fill the database tables. My test case contains only two entities and a simple session bean. I defined an one to many relationship (@OneToMany) and added the join column (using @JoinColumn). 
I managed to execute some simple queries on the "child" table, but whenever I tried to execute a query against the "parent" table I get a bunch of exceptions resulting in a NullPointerException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.setInverseRelation(JDBCStoreManager.java:451)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:411)
```

I did a lot of queries in the internet (enhancement, additional properties in persistence.xml, ...), but nothing helped.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`